# die when prompted for password in perl

Tags: perl, ssh

I have a script that is using a ssh key for connecting to a remote server for a specific user. However, id the user information is changed and the keys are not updated, the script will hang waiting for a password.

How can I trap this and throw DIE when prompted for a password?

For example, if I use:

```
system("ssh -C USER@someserver.com -i /.ssh/USER.key ...");
```

and USER is not the same USER in USER.key, it hangs waiting for a password. I would rather have it die.

What is the best way to handle this without using a perl module?

Comment: This question is not about Perl, but about how to invoke the `ssh` command line client.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
system('ssh -o BatchMode=yes -C USER@someserver.com -i /.ssh/USER.key ...');
```

The BatchMode option will prevent ssh from prompting for passwords, and will simply terminate if a password is required.

Comment: You should also use warnings.

Comment: I am assuming that this is one line in a larger script.  I'm not going to throw `use warnings;` in all of my script snippets, thank you very much.

Comment: Using `warnings`, even for this one line snippet, would point out a likely bug in this line (and in the OP).

Comment: Yes, the `@` interpolation.  As this question is *actually* about influencing the behavior of the `ssh` program, I'm not terribly concerned with that... the OP will be aware, either way, that something is broken.  However, I will change the quotes to apostrophes to resolve the issue.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for a simple solution. Simple is always best and this is great!

Answer (score 4):

When you use [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) like that, you relinquish control to [`ssh`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1). I recommend you look at the options for [`ssh`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1).

Also, you should use [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using any of the SSH modules availables from CPAN as Net::SSH2 or Net::OpenSSH?